# How to compare two CSV file using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, csv, azure-powershell, powershell-4.0, powershell-remoting

I have a csv file call Full-List.csv that have columns like this

```
Old_URL    Number
```

I have another csv file Sub-List.csv that have columns like this

```
Old_URL  New_URL Title  Owner
```

I'm just wondering how can I compare the two csv file using Old_URL column and output to another csv file that look something like this. Basically it'll include a "Number" column now.

```
New_URL  Title  Owner  Number
```

```
$left = Import-Csv 'C:\Users\Downloads\New folder\Full-List.csv'
$right = Import-Csv 'C:\Users\Downloads\New folder\Sub-List.csv'

Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $left -DifferenceObject $right -Property Old_URL -IncludeEqual -ExcludeDifferent | 
    ForEach-Object {
        $iItem = $_
        $ileft = $left.Where({$_.Old_URL -eq $iItem.Old_URL })
        $iright = $right.Where({$_.Old_URL -eq $iItem.Old_URL})
        [pscustomobject]@{
             New_URL = $iright.New_URL
             Number =$ileft.Number
             Title = $iright.Title
             Owner =$iright.Owner
        }
    } | Export-Csv 'C:\Users\Downloads\New folder\Combined.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

There are matching Old_URL in both file but some reason my Combined.csv output is empty so any help or suggestion would be really appreciated.

Comment: Using this [`Join-Object script`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Join)/[`Join-Object Module`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/JoinModule) (see also: [In Powershell, what's the best way to join two tables into one?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45483110/1701026)): `Import-Csv .\Full-List.Csv |Join (Import-Csv .\Sub-List.Csv) -on Old_URL |Export-Csv  .\Combined.Csv`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should really consider using [hash table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_hash_tables?view=powershell-7.2) for this, [`Group-Object -AsHashtable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object?view=powershell-7.3#-ashashtable) does a great job simplifying this process. Once you have your lookup table you can enumerate the `Full-List` CSV and output only those objects having a correlated `Old_URL` value:

```
$map = Import-Csv path\to\Sub-List.csv | Group-Object Old_URL -AsHashTable -AsString

Import-Csv path\to\Full-List.csv | ForEach-Object {
    if($map.ContainsKey($_.Old_URL)) {
        [pscustomobject]@{
            New_URL = $map[$_.Old_URL].New_URL
            Title   = $map[$_.Old_URL].Title
            Owner   = $map[$_.Old_URL].Owner
            Number  = $_.Number
        }
    }
} | Export-Csv path\to\mergedCsv.csv -NoTypeInformation
```